# Problems about symmetric groups

Tags: permutations, symmetric-groups

We just finished a lesson about determinants and the symmetric group with all what comes with it ( permutations, transpositions etc... ), except we didn't do group theory ( we only see it next year ), just some general algebra. But I'd like to know if there are some nice problems online about permutations ( like for example Muirhead's inequality ).

Thanks !

Comment: "Nice" is such a personal thing...and without grout theory that's even more limited. Also I'm not sure how Muirhead's ineq. fits in here...

Comment: Grout theory? Well, I guess you can apply it to tilings....

Comment: I don't know if they are available on-line, but John D. Dixon's **Problems in Group Theory** (Dover) Chapter 2 is about permutation groups, and de Souza and Silva's **Berkeley Problems in Mathematics**, section 6.5, is about $S_n$, $A_n$, $D_n$, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very general and you should probably specify what you are looking for exactly. One thing I always like to do when students learn about the symmetric group for the first time is talk about the Futurama episode [The prisoner of Benda](http://theinfosphere.org/The_Prisoner_of_Benda) where they ask a question about permutations and even provide an explicit, mathematically correct proof of the solution.

Comment: And this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8M4dUj7vZJc explains the episode and the proof very well.

Answer (score 0):

Let $1 < m < n$. Show that $\langle (1 2 \cdots m), (1 2 \cdots n) \rangle$ has a $3$-cycle. (I was trying to remember a problem that I have done in Isaacs' book. I might have remembered wrong, though I think it's right. But since you want a problem, if the statement is wrong, just tweak the problem and prove it wrong.)

Comment: Personally, this was one of the problems that I think was good to get my hands dirty when it comes to understanding some elementary computations and lemmas of symmetric groups.